# SQL query Average per Year

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Table which contains this data

```
Date         AveTemp
1849-03-01   25
1849-04-01   12
1849-05-01   30
1850-01-01   32
1850-02-01   22
```

i need to calculate the average of AveTemp per year SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have comparable data points in each year:

```
select strftime('%Y', date) as yyyy, avg(avetemp)
from t
group by strftime('%Y', date);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, i guess select Date,avg(AveTemp) from t group by Date; should also work right ?

Comment: Date             AveTemp   City
1849-03-01   25              Boston
1849-04-01   12              Boston
1849-05-01   30              NY
1850-01-01   32              London  
1850-02-01   22              London

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it... what if I need to calculate average AveTemp per year for each city

Comment: You would add `city` to the `group by` and `select`.